# how to use bootstrap list group in wordpress nav menu

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a bootstrap theme in wordpress. I am not very familiar with PHP but maybe you can help me.
i want a WordPress navigation out put like the following html code,

```
<div class="list-group">
<a href="#" class="list-group-item active">On the Spot</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>
```

Please someone can help me out?
Thanks.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu are you using this?

Answer (score 0):

Update the `include=` with the page id of the Wordpress pages you want in your menu.  I did not test, but should be close / a good start.

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse list-group">
    <ul class="nav pull-right navi list-group-item">
        <?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&include=,4,9,11,13,16'); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```